# In addition to the grammerly software, are there other better tools in English writing?

Tags: software

For non-English speakers, are there other useful tools besides grammerly software in English writing? Mainly check whether the sentence is authentic.

Comment: I test them with this: https://www.thoughtco.com/spell-checker-poem-by-mark-eckman-1692348  and not found one that finds **all** the errors... But I have the advantage of mother tongue... However, you might get better info by asking on the English Learners Stack. And is it "Grammarly"?

Comment: Should it be "grammarly" or "grammerly"?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to get someone to look over it for you. While leaps and bounds have been made in CS related to looking over papers (or just sentences), not one catches everything.

Your university may have a "homework help" department that students(usually undergrads) can use to get their material looked over (mine had services to help with writing and mathematics specifically). While I think it would be a little out of the ordinary I think it would be worth a shot to see if they would check over your paper for comprehension.